# Почему OSMDroid не видит offline карты?

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго времени суток!
Хочу встроить ОСМдроид оффлайн карты в свое приложение, перепробовал массу вариантов:
Манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

интернет не стал подключать ибо карты оффлайн, да и инет не используется.
В верстке стандартно:

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

В коде пробовал по этому примеру:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,parent,false);
    myOpenMapView = (MapView)v.findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    myOpenMapView.setUseDataConnection(false); //work from directory osmdroid
    myOpenMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
    myOpenMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myOpenMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    myOpenMapView.setMaxZoomLevel(15);
    myOpenMapView.setMinZoomLevel(12);
    BoundingBoxE6 bbox = new BoundingBoxE6(46.520131,30.774078,46.451105,30.686188);
    myOpenMapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(bbox);
    myMapController = (MapController) myOpenMapView.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(15);
    myMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(46.46766, 30.726013));
    return v;
}
```

не видит архив с картами.
Пробовал и по этому примеру:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DefaultResourceProxyImpl resProxy;
    resProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this.getApplicationContext());

    XYTileSource tSource;
    tSource = new XYTileSource("mbtiles",
    ResourceProxy.string.offline_mode,
    8, 15, 256, ".png", "http://who.cares/");

    SimpleRegisterReceiver sr = new SimpleRegisterReceiver(this);

    String packageDir = "/Maps";
    String p = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + packageDir;
    File f = new File(p, "HollandRoute.mbtiles");
    IArchiveFile[] files = { MBTilesFileArchive.getDatabaseFileArchive(f) };

    MapTileModuleProviderBase moduleProvider;
    moduleProvider = new MapTileFileArchiveProvider(sr, tSource, files);

    MapTileModuleProviderBase[] pBaseArray;
    pBaseArray = new MapTileModuleProviderBase[] { moduleProvider };

    MapTileProviderArray provider;
    provider = new MapTileProviderArray(tSource, null, pBaseArray);

    mapView = new BoundedMapView(this, resProxy, provider);

    double north = 52.6297;
    double east  =  5.3496;
    double south = 52.1613;
    double west  =  4.4638;
    BoundingBoxE6 bBox = new BoundingBoxE6(north, east, south, west);

    mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(bBox);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // Zoom in and go to Amsterdam
    MapController controller = mapView.getController();
    controller.setZoom(15);
    controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint(52.373444, 4.892229));
```

И такой код тоже не помог:

```
map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest",
ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_osm, 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{
"http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/...",
"http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/...",
"http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/...",
"http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/..."}));
```

Взято из GitHub:

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("YOUR MAP SOURCE", 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));
//....
map.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the network and test your zip loading. 
IMapController mapController = map.getController();
mapController.setZoom(_A ZOOM LEVEL YOU HAVE IN YOUR ZIP_);
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(_POSITION SOMEWHERE INSIDE YOUR MAP_);
mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
```

Так же безрезультатно, вместо карты просто сетка. Архив создавался в MOBAC osmdroid ZIP, лежит в на sd-карте `\osmdroid\Map.zip`. Аппарат ALPS V9 (LandRover V9) Android 4.4.2

Что я делаю не так? Или ткните носом в рабочий код, я в программировании не силен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю: OSMDroid не видит архив с тайлами на SD-карте потому, что архив должен размещаться на EXTERNAL_SD_CARD, а SD-карта вставляемая в аппарат является REMOVABLE_SD_CARD.
Добавив следующий код в приложение можно легко определить EXTERNAL_SD_CARD

```
 File checkDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "osmdroid/Maps");

    if(checkDir.exists()) {
     Log.d("Dir", "directory exist");
    } else {
     Log.d("Dir", "directory NOT exist");
     checkDir.mkdirs();
     Log.d("Dir", "directory create");
    }
```

на  EXTERNAL_SD_CARD будет создана папка osmdroid со вложенной папкой Maps. Именно в папку osmdroid и нужно определить zip архив с картами. Теперь код получился очень простой:

```
    map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("xUSSR.Roads.Visicom 2.0",null, 14, 19, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {}));
    map.setClickable(true);
    map.setUseDataConnection(false);
    map.setMaxZoomLevel(19);
    map.setMinZoomLevel(14);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    final GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(47.990554, 37.800179);
    final IMapController MC = map.getController();
    MC.setCenter(startPoint);
    MC.setZoom(19);
```

где xUSSR.Roads.Visicom 2.0 источник карт, именно его мы выбираем в МОВАС.